A Question Regarding Cartan’s Absorption Method
I want to ask a question from the book named “ Cartan for Beginners : Differential Geometry via Moving Frames and Exterior Differential Systems” as to how one can absorb an apparent torsion. Suppose that $J=\{\theta^a, \omega^i\}$ is Pffafian system with independence condition $\omega^1 \wedge \dotsc \wedge \omega^n \neq 0$. Let $I=\{\theta^a\}$ be an algebraic ideal and $\{\pi^{\epsilon}\}$ be the subspace complementary to the subspace spanned by $J$. So, say that our cotangent space is $T^{\ast}\Sigma=\{\theta^a, \omega^i, \pi^{\epsilon}\}$, where $\Sigma$ is a manifold embedded into the first jet-space $J^1$. Then, let:
$$d\theta^a = A_{\epsilon i}^a \pi^{\epsilon}\wedge \omega^i + T_{ij}^a \omega^i \wedge \omega^j \;\text{mod}\, I, $$
where summation over corresponding up and down indices are implied (Einstein notation) and mod $I$ means “quotient out by the algebraic ideal $I$”. So far so good: Torsion-free and torsion parts w.r.t. the ideal $I$. Then, in Ex#5.2.1, the first part:
Show that if $\tilde{\pi^{\epsilon}}=M_{\delta}^{\epsilon}\pi^{\epsilon}$ for some invertible matrix $M^{\epsilon}_{\delta}$, then the new apparent torsion $\tilde{T _{ij}^a}$ is identically zero iff the original apparent torsion $T_{ij}^a$ was identically zero. Conclude that the only possible way to absorb apparent torsion is to change the complement of the subspace $J \subset T^{\ast}\Sigma$ spanned by the $\pi^{\epsilon}$’s.
My question is the one in bold. The transformation he proposes has nothing to do with the subspace spanned by $J=\{\theta^a, \omega^i\}$. It is certainly true that $\tilde{T _{ij}^a}=T_{ij}^a$ after that transformation! If a transformation has no effect on the term (torsion term $T_{ij}^a$) that I want to be equal to $0$ (which is originally assumed to be not $0$), then what is the point of this transformation? How can I conclude that the right subspace where we should make modifications is the one perpendicular to the ideal J? What exactly am I missing?

What does "perpendicular" mean? You're choosing generators for a complementary subspace; their point is that you need to choose a different complementary subspace to annihilate $T$, not change the generators for the identical subspace.

@TedShifrin Yes, complementary subspace, I meant :) I’ve fixed it! I am not sure I understand what you wrote. By identical subspace you mean the one spanned by $J$, I assume? The confusing part to me is “how can you annhiliate something if your transformation does nothing to the original coefficients $T_{ij}^a$?” Torsion-free and torsion parts have different basis aterall.

It's still a complementary subspace, not the. That's the whole point. You need to modify the $\pi^\epsilon$ by adding appropriate multiples of $\omega^i$.

Professor @TedShifrin, I think there are some typos in your message. “not the…”? By the way, that is exactly the question of mine: “How did we end up with adding multiples of $\omega^i$?” So, ultimately, we should be looking for a transformation from the space ${\omega^i}$ to the space ${\pi^{\epsilon}}$? Why? Can you give me a hint; so that I can do some pen and paper work to see it?

I was distinguishing between the (which means there is a single possible one) and a (which suggests that there are many options). Some languages do not have definite/indefinite articles, so perhaps that's the confusion. Anyhow, write $\tilde\pi^\epsilon = M^\epsilon_\delta\pi^\delta + a^\epsilon_i\omega^i$ for some functions $M^\epsilon_\delta$ and $a^\epsilon_i$ and then differentiate. I'm sure the book has shown you how to do this, as this is the main tool at this point.

Professor @TedShifrin, I think I’ve finally understood what Prof. Ivey and you tried to convey! It is all about “indeterminancy” on basis for M-C forms, ${\pi^{\epsilon}}$, and torsion coefficients, ${T^a_{ij}}$. It is elegantly explained (at least for me) in Chapter-3, starting on page 21 by Prof. Gardner in Gardner_Equivalence. Equations $4$, $5$, and $6$, in particular. The keyword “indeterminancy” has enlightened me :)
